# Query in a SearchView is lost after closing and opening it again

Tags: android, searchview

I'm working on a Fragment in which I have a SearchView. If I close the SearchView and then reopen it, the query I typed is gone.

The problem is I don't want this behavior. I want the behavior like the SearchView in the Google Play store, where the query is still there if I close and open it.

May it have something to do with the fact that I don't have a searchable.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an onCloseListener according to the documentation:

> Returns true if the listener wants to override the default behavior of
>   clearing the text field and dismissing it, false otherwise.

See 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnCloseListener.html#onClose()

I'm uncertain if this works properly after looking at the source code for SearchView which seems to only call the onCloseListener if the query TextView is empty.

Check out [SearchView.onCloseClicked()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java#L1176) to see what is happening:

```
   private void onCloseClicked() {
        CharSequence text = mQueryTextView.getText();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
            if (mIconifiedByDefault) {
                // If the app doesn't override the close behavior
                if (mOnCloseListener == null || !mOnCloseListener.onClose()) {
                    // hide the keyboard and remove focus
                    clearFocus();
                    // collapse the search field
                    updateViewsVisibility(true);
                }
            }
        } else {
            mQueryTextView.setText("");
            mQueryTextView.requestFocus();
            setImeVisibility(true);
        }

    }
```

So if overriding the onCloseListener doesn't work that's why.

Since SearchView is public you can extend the class and fix the logic of onCloseClicked() or override onActionViewExpanded / onActionViewCollapsed to restore and save the query string.

You could also try saving the query in your OnQueryTextListener and then calling setQuery(savedQuery, false) in onOptionsItemSelected.

Comment: As you suggested I tried the OnCloseListener and the saving the query in my OnQueryTextListener, to restore it in onOptionsItemSelected. Both solutions did not work. I had to override the SearchView. I want to override the onCloseClicked(), but because it's private I couldn't.

So I had to override onActionViewExpanded() and onActionViewCollapsed(). It's a little hacky, but it works :)!

Comment: Yeah it looked like the code for onCloseClicked is wrong. I actually reimplemented my own SearchView (fairly straightforward) to get it to work the way I want it to.